# How to calculate regression between 2 columns in dataframe

Tags: r, lm

I'm learning how to do regression in R, and I decided to try and regress GOOG to AAPL.

Here's what I did

```
getSymbols("AAPL", from="2011-01-01", to="2013-01-01")
getSymbols("GOOG", from="2011-01-01", to="2013-01-01")
lmdata=data.frame(Cl(AAPL),Cl(GOOG))
res=lm(lmdata)

plot(lmdata, main="Linear regression between GOOG and AAPL")
abline(res)
```

The result looks like this

[image: didn't work]

Obviously, some different regression was computed, and I'm suspecting that the software computed regression of AAPL closing price to it's date

```
> head(lmdata)
           AAPL.Close GOOG.Close
2011-01-03     329.57   604.3510
2011-01-04     331.29   602.1210
2011-01-05     334.00   609.0711
2011-01-06     333.73   613.5011
2011-01-07     336.12   616.4411
2011-01-10     342.45   614.2110
```

How do I compute regression between AAPL and GOOG?

Comment: That's interesting no error was raised as you have no formula in your `lm` only data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `lm` you need to specify the formula and data in the call:

```
res=lm(GOOG.Close ~ AAPL.Close, data=lmdata)
```

Then the model and plot will be correct.

[image]